# Main view get called again after a partial view has been returned through ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which job is to display a list of orders currently stored in the BD. It works like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Displays the list of all the suppliers orders filled by now.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public ActionResult CheckoutSupplierOrders()
{
    int totalCount;

    List<OrderInfo> listOrders = mOrderManager.ListSupplierOrders(out totalCount);

    Session[CHECKOUT_PAGE_INDEX] = General.CreatePageIndex(totalCount);

    Session[CHECKOUT_PAGE_NUMBER] = 1;

    return View(listOrders);
}
```

Here's how the view is rendered:

```
@model List<MagicAdmin2.Models.OrderInfo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Supplier Orders";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fetchButton').click(function () {
            alert("clicked!");
            var pageNumber = $('#pageNum').val();
            var sortOrder = $('#sortOrder').val();
            var showOrderType = $('#orderType').val();
            var showOrderDesc = $('#orderDesc').val();
            var showDateCreated = $('#orderCreated').val();
            var showDateCreatedSymbol = $('#orderCreatedSymbol').val();
            var showDateModified = $('#orderModified').val();
            var showDateModifiedSymbol = $('#orderModifiedSymbol').val();

            getNextPage(pageNumber, showOrderType, showOrderDesc, showDateCreated, showDateCreatedSymbol, showDateModified, showDateModifiedSymbol, sortOrder);
        });

        function getNextPage(pageNumber, showOrderType, showOrderDesc, showDateCreated, showDateCreatedSymbol, showDateModified, showDateModifiedSymbol, sortOrder) {
            ShowProgress();
            $.get("@Url.Action("GetSuppliersNextPage", "ManageOrders")", {
                _pageNumber: pageNumber,
                _orderType: showOrderType,
                _orderDesc: showOrderDesc,
                _dateCreated: showDateCreated,
                _dateCreatedSymbol: showDateCreatedSymbol,
                _dateModified: showDateModified,
                _dateModifiedSymbol: showDateModifiedSymbol,
                _sortOrder: sortOrder
            }, function (data) {
                $('#resultsDiv').html(data);
                HideProgress();
            });
        }
    });
</script>

<h2>
    List supplier orders
</h2>

<br/>

@{
    Html.RenderAction("FilterSupplierOrders", "PartialViews");
}

@{
    int pageNumber = (int)Session["checkoutOrderPageNumber"];

    @Html.Hidden("pageNum", pageNumber, new { @id = "pageNum" })
}

<div id="resultsDiv">
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("CheckoutResultTable", Model);
    }
</div>
```

The script is there to catch the filters rendered by the `@{
        Html.RenderAction("FilterSupplierOrders", "PartialViews");
    }` line. To avoid a missing bug, here's how the filters work:

```
public ActionResult FilterSupplierOrders()
{
    return PartialView("Filters/FilterSuppliersOrders", new SupplierOrdersFilter());
}
```

And the partial view:

```
@model MagicAdmin2.Utility.PageFilters.SupplierOrdersFilter

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="blackBorder defaultBaseStyle">
        <h3 style="background: #efeeef; margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 10px; padding: 0 10px; width: 50px;">Filters</h3>
        Filter by Order Type: @Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.OrderType, Model.ListOrderTypes, "All", new { @id = "orderType"})
        Description: @Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item.Description, new { @id = "orderDesc"})
        Date Created: @Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.DateCreatedSymbol, Model.SymbolList, String.Empty, new { @id = "orderCreatedSymbol"}) @Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item.DateCreated, new { @class = "datePicker", @title = "Choose a date", @id = "orderCreated"})
        Date Modified: @Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.DateModifiedSymbol, Model.SymbolList, String.Empty, new { @id = "orderModifiedSymbol"}) @Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item.DateModified, new { @class = "datePicker", @title = "Choose a date", @id = "orderModified"})
        <input type="submit" value="Fetch" id="fetchButton"/>
    </div>
}
```

So the reason being that the rest of the view is rendered in the `CheckoutResultTable` partial view:

```
@using MagicAdmin2.Utility.Data
@model List<MagicAdmin2.Models.OrderInfo>

@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    @Html.Hidden("sortOrder", Session["checkoutOrderSort"], new { @id = "sortOrder"})

    if (Session["checkoutOrderPagesIndex"] != null)
    {
        <div class="center">
            <span>Pages:</span>
            @{
                List<int> pages = (List<int>)Session["checkoutOrderPagesIndex"];

                int inventoryPageNumber = (int)Session["checkoutOrderPageNumber"];

                if (pages.Count <= 10)
                {
                    foreach (int page in pages)
                    {
                        if (page == inventoryPageNumber)
                        {
                            <span>@page</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-page="@page" class="pageLink">@page</a>    
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pages.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int pageToShow = pages[i];

                        if (pageToShow == pages[0] || pageToShow == pages[pages.Count - 1])
                        {
                            if (pageToShow == inventoryPageNumber)
                            {
                                <span>@pageToShow</span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-page="@pageToShow" class="pageLink">@pageToShow</a>    
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (pageToShow == inventoryPageNumber)
                            {
                                <span>@pageToShow</span>
                            }
                            else if (pages[i] > inventoryPageNumber - 4 && pages[i] < inventoryPageNumber + 5)
                            {
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-page="@pageToShow" class="pageLink">@pageToShow</a>    
                            }
                            else if ((pages[i] == 2 && inventoryPageNumber > 4) || (pages[i] == pages.Count - 1 && inventoryPageNumber < pages.Count - 2))
                            {
                                <span>...</span>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>     
    }
    <table id="resultTable">
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Date Created
            </th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date Modified</th>
            <th>
                Type
            </th>
            <th>
                State
            </th>
            <th>Shipping</th>
            <th>Billing</th>
            <th>
                # Items
            </th>
            <th>Prices and charges</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            var className = i % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";

            <tr class="@className order orderState-@MagicAdmin2.Utility.Helpers.General.GetEnumDescription(Model[i].mOrderState)">
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mOrderID)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mOrderDateCreated)</td>
                <td class="align-left">@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mOrderDescription)</td>
                <td>@(Model[i].mOrderDateModified != null ? Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mOrderDateModified)
                          : Html.Label(ValueDomain.FIELD_UNAVAILABLE))</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mOrderType)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mOrderState)</td>
                <td class="align-left">
                    Name:        <span class="bold">@Model[i].mShippingFirstName</span><br/>
                    Address:     <span class="bold">@Model[i].mShippingAddress</span><br/>
                    City:        <span class="bold">@Model[i].mShippingCity</span><br/>
                    Country:     <span class="bold">@Model[i].mShippingCountry</span><br/>
                    Region:      <span class="bold">@Model[i].mShippingRegion</span><br/>
                    Postal Code: <span class="bold">@Model[i].mShippingPostalCode</span><br/>
                </td>
                <td class="align-left">
                    Name:        <span class="bold">@Model[i].mBillingLastName</span><br/>
                    Address:     <span class="bold">@Model[i].mBillingAddress</span><br/>
                    City:        <span class="bold">@Model[i].mBillingCity</span><br/>
                    Country:     <span class="bold">@Model[i].mBillingCountry</span><br/>
                    Region:      <span class="bold">@Model[i].mBillingRegion</span><br/>
                    Postal Code: <span class="bold">@Model[i].mBillingPostalCode</span><br/>
                </td>
                <td>@Model[i].mOrderItemCount</td>
                <td id="priceField" class="align-left adjustedField">
                    Detail Amount: <span class="bold">@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mOrderDetailAmount) $</span><br/>
                    Taxes:         <span class="bold">@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mOrderTaxes) $</span><br/>
                    Shipping Cost: <span class="bold">@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mOrderShippingCost) $</span><br/>
                    Handling Cost: <span class="bold">@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mOrderHandlingCost) $</span><br/>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Item Total", "DisplaySupplierOrdersToCheckout", new { @_sortOrder = ViewBag.TotalSortParm } ):    <span class="bold">@Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mOrderTotal) $</span><br/>
                </td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Confirm reception", "SelectOrder", new { _orderID = Model[i].mOrderID })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    if (Session["checkoutOrderPagesIndex"] != null)
    {
        <div class="center">
            <span>Pages:</span>
            @{
                List<int> pages = (List<int>)Session["checkoutOrderPagesIndex"];

                int inventoryPageNumber = (int)Session["checkoutOrderPageNumber"];

                if (pages.Count <= 10)
                {
                    foreach (int page in pages)
                    {
                        if (page == inventoryPageNumber)
                        {
                            <span>@page</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-page="@page" class="pageLink">@page</a>    
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pages.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int pageToShow = pages[i];

                        if (pageToShow == pages[0] || pageToShow == pages[pages.Count - 1])
                        {
                            if (pageToShow == inventoryPageNumber)
                            {
                                <span>@pageToShow</span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-page="@pageToShow" class="pageLink">@pageToShow</a>    
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (pageToShow == inventoryPageNumber)
                            {
                                <span>@pageToShow</span>
                            }
                            else if (pages[i] > inventoryPageNumber - 4 && pages[i] < inventoryPageNumber + 5)
                            {
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-page="@pageToShow" class="pageLink">@pageToShow</a>    
                            }
                            else if ((pages[i] == 2 && inventoryPageNumber > 4) || (pages[i] == pages.Count - 1 && inventoryPageNumber < pages.Count - 2))
                            {
                                <span>...</span>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>     
    }
}
else
{
    <span class="errorMessage">There are no orders to checkout.</span>
}
```

is because if the use at that moment choose to filter the obtained data, say, by name, he may, using a jquery method that calls the controller method:

```
public PartialViewResult GetSuppliersNextPage(int _pageNumber, string _orderType, string _orderDesc, string _dateCreated, string _dateCreatedSymbol,
                                            string _dateModified, string _dateModifiedSymbol, string _sortOrder)
{
    int totalCount;

    string sortOrder;

    if (Session[CHECKOUT_SORT_ORDER] == null)
    {
        sortOrder = _sortOrder;

        Session[CHECKOUT_SORT_ORDER] = _sortOrder;
    }
    else
    {
        sortOrder = (string)Session[CHECKOUT_SORT_ORDER];

        switch (_sortOrder)
        {
            default:
                sortOrder = _sortOrder;
                break;
        }
    }

    ISupplierOrderParams filterParams = new SupplierOrderParams(_pageNumber, _orderType, _orderDesc, _dateCreated, _dateCreatedSymbol, _dateModified, _dateModifiedSymbol, sortOrder);

    List<OrderInfo> listItems = mOrderManager.ListSupplierOrdersNextPage(filterParams, out totalCount);

    Session[CHECKOUT_PAGE_INDEX] = General.CreatePageIndex(totalCount);

    Session[CHECKOUT_PAGE_NUMBER] = _pageNumber;

    return PartialView("CheckoutResultTable", listItems);
}
```

My main trouble is that the method is called appropriately and does it rendering. However right after the rendering of the partial view is done, the `CheckoutSupplierOrders()` controller method is called (WHY?!?), thus destroying the purpose of the ajax call. And I don't know why this occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that the button, when clicked, not only triggers the load of the partial view, but also submits the form. After the form is submitted and the response from server is received (response being the same page), browser renders this response and you see exactly the same page you are on.

To avoid such behavior, prevent it in the click handler:

```
$('#fetchButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Woah! Never thought about that! I'll try it out.

Comment: Woot! Seems like it was the only problem. Now since I have a few input buttons placed like in the framework up here, I'll change the behavior for those. Thank you!

Comment: I love Stackoverflow, I've been spending the last 3-4 hours trying to find my answer, finally post my problem here, and it took 10 minutes... :D